# How to add an element to an array when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, event-listener

I would like that when I check a checkbox, an element is added to the array, and when I uncheck the check box. The code is working, but not properly, and I can’t figure out where it came from.

```
var tableau= ["0"];

var checkBox_numero = document.getElementById("numero");

    checkBox_numero.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Checkbox is checked..
            tableau.push("numero");
        } else {
            // Checkbox is not checked..
            tableau.shift();
        }
    });
    console.log(tableau);
```

Comment: 1. Welcome!
2. StackOverflow is in English only.
3. Title is not clear.

Comment: How to add an element to an array when a checkbox is checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **push** the numero to your array but you want to delete it with **shift**, that doesn't works right, because push puts the element at the end and shift takes it from the beinnig away.
So just use **pop** to take it from the end.

```js
var tableau= ["0"];

var checkBox_numero = document.getElementById("numero");

    checkBox_numero.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Checkbox is checked..
            tableau.push("numero");
        } else {
            // Checkbox is not checked..
            tableau.pop();
        }
         console.log(tableau);
    });
    console.log(tableau);
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='numero'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have [“0”] as the first element in the array. Then you push numero to the array, so it looks like this: [“0”, numero].

Then when you call shift: it removes the first element, which is “0”.

The best way would be to find and remove that checkbox from the array.